# Put data from a text file into an HTML form

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a text file that shows a list of currency exchanges rates.

I have read the first line of the text file content and I need this line to be inserted into the input form.

#### Perl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);
#use Data::Dumper;
#use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
 
my %data;

$data{name} = $q->param('name');

print header;

my $file = '/admin/currencyX.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while ( my $line = <$info> )  {   
    print $line, "<br>";    
    last if $. == 1;
}

print
    start_html('A Simple Example'),
    h1('A Simple Example'),
    start_form,
    "What's your value? <br>",
    textfield(-name => 'name', -class => 'nm', -value => '$line'),
    p,
    submit(-value => 'Add', -name => 'ed'),
    end_form,
    hr;

if ( $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST" ) { 
          
    if ( $data{name} eq '' ) {
        print "Please provide the input";
        exit;
    }
 
    #print "response " . Dumper \%data;
}

if ( param() ) {
    print 
    "Your name is",em(param('name')),
    hr;
}

print end_html;
```

The text file has a similar values like

#### Text file

```
AFN Afghan Afghani  73.0556951371   0.0136881868
ALL Albanian Lek    108.3423252926  0.0092300031
DZD Algerian Dinar  117.9799583224  0.0084760159
AOA Angolan Kwanza  249.2606313396  0.0040118650
ARS Argentine Peso  28.2508833695   0.0353971232
AMD Armenian Dram   482.0941933740  0.0020742834
```

I need a correction to make this work.

Comment: Warning: The [HTML Generation functions (which you are using) should no longer be used](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used) and [nor should CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE).

Comment: A correction to make what work fine? You don't have any input tags in your code and I can't imagine what they would be doing anyway. Are you sure you don't want a select tag?

Comment: @ChrisTurner `"What's your value? <br>",textfield(-name =>'name', -class =>'nm', -value =>'$line'),` will create a text input, but i need the input to have `$line` as it is at `print $line,"<br>";`

Comment: @Borodin if i knew any perl i would not have asked that question , sorry for my miss understanding. dont mind about any text like `your name` all i need is to have the value shown at the txt  file  imported to the html value.

Comment: @dean: *"if i knew any perl i would not have asked that question"*  It is incumbent on you to acquire a working knowledge of the tools you're trying to use before you post a question here asking for free assistance. We are not here to replace a simple lack of knowledge, but to help out knowledgeable people who have tried their best and are still struggling with an issue. I'm sure you can do better than just copying someone else's work.

Comment: @dean: *"dont mind about any text like `your name`"*  You have no business posting such shabby code when you are requesting the favour of free advice. I have had to format it to be able to read it, and there are still statements—both commented and live—that are nothing at all to do with the problem at hand. Take a look at [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and apply them to your future questions.

Comment: @Borodin, please save your fighting gloves, i learn from doing errors and making some improvements, asking that question plus all the text in it was necessary as per my understanding. Am sorry to you all if this question has provoked you , but i needed an answer not a correction to any small text provided there in. Am so sorry, but i still need a solution if applicable.

Comment: @dean: *"i learn from doing errors and making some improvements"* Most people do. But you are making lazy errors and getting other people to fix them. You still haven't described what your program does that isn't what you want. You really need to read those links.

Comment: Thanks for all of your effort , i have finally configured it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
textfield(-name => 'name', -class => 'nm', -value => '$line'),
```

Your problem appears to be that you have put `$line` in single quotes - which stops it being interpolated. Try just removing them.

```
textfield(-name => 'name', -class => 'nm', -value => $line),
```

Comment: "It failed" is a terrible way to report a problem. What (exactly) did you do? What unexpected behaviour did you see? You're a senior programmer. You should know how to report problems clearly.

Comment: before posting my problem, i tried all the possibilities including your preferred answer and i got a 500 internal sever error. hence not okay

Comment: And you know where to get more information about a 500 error, I hope. You are, after all, a senior programmer :-)